# API to get POSIX timezone in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to do some Date/Time manipulations using the Boost API. However, in order to do so I need to first get the local time in POSIX time format, seconds since the epoch.

What C++ API will provide local time in POSIX time format?

Comment: You clearly didn't google "POSIX time format in C++"

Comment: Can you please let me know the link. I tried lot of times but I didn't find.

Comment: Do you want to get the timezone, or the date, or the time? You'll find that precision is fairly important in our field. Pick one.

Comment: I did all the googling before coming here. If you are not going to answer that is fine. But who are you to question my credentials. First you both learn how to behave with others. @enhzflep, I saw your profile, you have 26 years of experience. But what is the fn use, if you don't know how to behave with others? Lightness Races in Orbit, don't think you are the only talented person on this earth and please keep in mind that Global Logic is not requesting you to join. We want people with talent but not with head weight.

Comment: If a person is asking question, that means either he didn't work on that or he  didn't find it on google. Some times I saw people are saying that you didn't google the question. Do they want us to upload some camera recordings as proofs that we googled the question before coming here. Are you discouraging people to post questions on stack overflow?

Comment: Here is a timezone library that may or may not be of help to you.  If it is helpful, it is free and open source: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Comment: @HowardHinnant Thanks a lot. It is really helpful.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't know. I read the OP's question and it was clear what was being asked. Twice the question was asked, "...any API to get the local time in POSIX time format in C++". Seems clear enough for me.

Comment: @Chimera: Title is _"API to get POSIX timezone in C++"_, question says _"I need to get the date"_ and _"in POSIX time format"_ and _"get whether Day light saving is active or not and other day light information"_ and _"get the local time in POSIX time format"_. That's several completely different requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition of [POSIX Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

You probably want to use [std::time](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time).

Here is an example:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
    std::cout << std::asctime(std::localtime(&result))
              << result << " seconds since the Epoch\n";
}
```

And here is some information on the [Boost Posix Time Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#date_time.posix_time.ptime_class)

Comment: Thanks Chimera. I need the date in the below format "EST+5 EDT,M4.1.0/2,M10.5.0/2"

Comment: Why is my answer downvoted? The OP asked for time in POSIX time format, which I supplied. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: The OP asked for all sorts of things, all at the same time. "Answering" such nonsense only encourages it, which is perhaps why someone saw fit to punish you for your well-intentioned yet misguided efforts.

Comment: I don't know about people's mentality. But have a question and I need an answer and Chimera provided it.

Comment: (For the record, the downvote did not come from me.)

Comment: @kadina: This answer covers roughly 25% of your question. Please clarify your question for the benefit of future readers. If you only needed to know how to get POSIX time, then make your question just say that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I read the question and saw only ONE question. " Can any one please let me know any API to get the local time in POSIX time format in C++? " The other stuff was explaining WHY that was needed.

Comment: _"I need to get the date in POSIX time format"_ _"please let me know any API to get the local time in POSIX time format in C++"_ Direct problem statements, contradicting. Not sure how else to break it down for you! Doesn't matter now anyway I suppose as the question has little chance of recovery.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess we are just interpreting the question differently. Which means that perhaps it should be editing to more clear.